# I lost my Python packages after I uninstalled/reinstalled Python via Homebrew. Is there a way I can recover a list of what I had?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, homebrew

I have Python installed on macOS via homebrew. I recently uninstalled it and reinstalled it, thinking that all my packages would be safe, but like an idiot, I used `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python` by accident so this got rid of my packages as well. Now `pip list` is just showing me whatever ships as default with Python.

My backups can't help me here because there were some that I installed since the last backup that I don't even remember the names of. Is there any way I can recover a list of all the packages I had installed?

Perhaps from some cache?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `.pip/pip.log` in your home directory? Probably limited usefulness, but a little something still. If nothing else works, probably review your imports and `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` files.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately no pip.log, but good tip, thanks anyway. I've written the majority of them down by reviewing my imports in my projects.